how to pass an array name to the controller from an input with name that is array in html without using ajax, just pass it to controllers parameter
<div class="col-md-3 ingname">
  <input class="form-control ingredient-name" placeholder="Ingredient Name" id="ingredientName[]" name="ingredientName[]" required />
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 ingqty">
  <input class="form-control ingredient-quantity" placeholder="Quantity" type="number" min="0" id="ingredientQty[]" name="ingredientQty[]" required/>
</div>

how to pass these inputs to a controller
is this correct?
public ActionResult UploadRecipe(Recipe recipe, string ingcount, string moodid, string[] ingredientName, int[] ingredientQty, string[] ingredientUnit) {


Apparently, you can only bind these data type in html input tags.
By removing [] from the input name you can get values in the controller.
But you can't get a array of string or int in controller directly. What you can do is convert array to string with JSON.stringify(arr) and bind it with text input, then convert it back to array in your controller.
